Looking for a wifi/BT controlled low pressure water valve
I have a gravity fed irrigation system with approximately 10' elevation drop with 1" PVC main outlet ball valve. The water runs through 50' of garden hose before connecting to about 150' of drip tape. I want to semi-automate the watering process. I’m searching for a water valve that has Bluetooth and/or wifi connectivity, that can be opened/closed at the touch of a button via app and/or at the unit itself. That runs on USB power (preferred) or 12V DC. I have a solar setup for an on demand water pump. The solar controller is connected to a 100W 12V panel, 12V 12Ah LiFePO4 battery, and diaphragm pump. The solar controller has two 5V2A USB ports that are always live.
These smart valves seem a bit bulky. Is there anything on the market that is less bulky? Simpler? Or am I overthinking my setup?
Suggestions please

If you are willing to go Zigbee instead of WiFi/BLE, you can check out https://zigbee.blakadder.com/misc.html and search for "valve", you'll find a few, both of the same kind as the one above and simpler/smaller ones. May be used as a pointer for possible suppliers, many have both BLE or Wifi and Zigbee versions of the same product.

This is more an "IOT" question (Internet of things) question then a gardening one.   How much of a hacker are you?  This can be built with "relatively low" (but still some knowledge using an ESP8266 or ESP32 board + a relay + case - there is a whole ecosystem of hackers doing this.  You could buy something like https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005006604920637.htm and flash it with software like tasmota.  I am aware of

Have a look at https://www.shelly.com/en/products/shop/shelly-1  -  Shelly software is easy to use compared to a roll-your-own if you can find one which will work with your voltages.  (I've not used it with 12 volts, but it claims to support 12v.  Its worth double checking before you buy though)

I also found https://sonoff.tech/product/diy-smart-switches/micro/ - That said, it occurs to me that getting a solenoid that will work at 5v and low current will be difficult. I did find https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005005244477455.html?spm=a2g0o.order_list.order_list_main.14.5940180255BBtO and simiar which will work with 12 volts - which may work with the Shelly suggestion above, but won't work at 5 volts.

Those smart valves are neat valve-turners, I've never seen one like that before.  A 'solenoid valve' would have been my first thought, and will probably get you a smaller form factor.


There are a wide variety of bluetooth irrigation valves available. The "hose end timer" type would appear to be suitable for your hose setup and far more compact than the behemoth you show. Those can operate as a timer or only when you tell them to, as you prefer.
No endorsement of any, I actually bought something that specifically does not have bluetooth, just a direct solar timer control (with rain sensor input to not run when wet) of a 3/4" pipe valve. But I saw plenty of them and I'm sure there are more now.
Most are battery powered rather than having a direct power input. Some (not the example below) can control multiple hose outputs from a single timer/control.

Image source
